# Angular 6 redirect on timeout

Tags: angular, session-timeout

I am using angular 6 and want to implement the idle timeout to an error page.
How do I do it?

Also need to reset the time for any Interruptions like click, scroll etc.

ng2-idle doesn't seem to be active, I have installed it but it's not recognized in the vs code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the angular-user-idle package which works with angular 6. And its also properly documented so it should be easier for you to use.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-user-idle

Comment: getting the follwoing error                                                                                 
 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Object../node_modules/angular-user-idle/fesm5/angular-user-idle.js

Comment: Seems you'll need to update your rxjs version to work around this